# why does if(number <=10) not work?

Tags: javascript, numbers

```
var way = 'up';
var m25 = {
    'n': 10
};

for (var somelongnumber = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    if (way === 'up') {
        m25.n = m25.n + 5;
        if (m25.n >= 90) {
            way = 'down';
        }
    } else {
        m25.n = m25.n - 5;
        if (m25.n <= 10) {
            way = 'down';
        }
    }

    console.log(way + m25.n);
}
```

this console.logs:

```
up15
up20
up25
up30
up35
up40
up45
up50
up55
up60
up65
up70
up75
up80
up85
down90
down85
down80
down75
down70
down65
down60
down55
down50
down45
down40
down35
down30
down25
down20
down15
down10
down5
down0
down-5
down-10
down-15
down-20
down-25
down-30
down-35
down-40
down-45
down-50
down-55
```

why does it go past zero? I am very confused!

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: In your if-else block - else{m25.n=m25.n - 5;if(m25.n<=10){way='down';}} this should be way = 'up'.

Comment: The code shown should give an error along the lines of `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined`, given that you declare a variable called `somelongnumber` at the point where you should declare `i`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should format your code so it's easier to read. then you might notice your mistake. `if (m25.n <= 10) way = 'down';` should be `'up'`

```
var way = 'up';
var m25 = {
    'n': 10
};

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (way === 'up') {
        m25.n = m25.n + 5;
        if (m25.n >= 90) {
            way = 'down';
        }
    } else {
        m25.n = m25.n - 5;
        if (m25.n <= 10) {
            way = 'up';
        }
    }

    console.log(way + m25.n);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly it (and why I posted after Levi). Format your code - it makes errors jump out at you more easily and makes things much more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

When it sees that is <=10, it sets way to "down," when you intended it to be "up"

Answer (score 0):

It's because you never reassign way back to "up". You have to edit your second if statement inside the else...

```
else {
    m25.n = m25.n - 5;
    if (m25.n <= 10) {
        way = 'up';  // RIGHT HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared i. Instead you are using somelongnumber...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want `up` again in the second if? `(m25.n <= 10) way = 'down';` should be '`up`'

And also you might want `i` in the for inside of `somelongnumber`.

### **Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fENmu/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
   if (m25.n <= 10) {
        way = 'up';
    }
```

And:

```
while (m25.n >= 0) {
    console.log(way + m25.n);
}
```